# Moving runtime created objects using c# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I have created an object at runtime by using drag and drop and I am moving the object and resizing the object by using `Input.getmousebutton`.

When I try to move object I am holding the mouse button and I can move it,   but when I release the button and move the cursor to the empty space and then click the mouse button, the object is moved here.

This is my main problem, but I also have to move camera towards object for zoom view.

**MyCode is:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
public class ClickAction : MonoBehaviour {
    //float distance=10;
    public GameObject gm;
    public string obj=null;
    public Destroyer destroy;
    //public MoveObject move;
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;
    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if(gm)
            {
              gm.GetComponent<GameObject>();
              gm.transform.position=new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,1);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
        {
            Ray toMouse = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit rhInfo;
            bool didHit = Physics.Raycast (toMouse, out rhInfo, 500.0f);
            if (didHit) 
            {
                gm=rhInfo.collider.gameObject;
                Debug.Log (rhInfo.collider.name+"--"+gameObject.name);
                obj=rhInfo.collider.name;
                //move.OnMouseDown();
                //move.OnMouseDrag();
                //Calling Destroyer script to destroy object
                destroy.getName(obj);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton (1)) 
        {
            if (gm) 
            {
                gm.GetComponent<GameObject> ();
                //gm.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.3F, .3F, .3F);
                gm.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `gm.GetComponent<GameObject>()` doesn't do anything because you aren't assigning the result to anything.

Comment: I think that gm.GetComponent<GameObject>() will return null anyway, as components inherit MonoBehaviour not GameObject

Answer (score 0):

First part of the question:

The object moves on the second click because both `Input.GetButtonDown(0)` and `Input.GetButton(0)` are called in the frame the button is first held down.

See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

Both parts are getting called because you have two if statements when you probably mean to have:

`if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
 ...
}
else if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
 ...
}`

Also, if you want to test for a mouse click you are better using `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` as this will happen when the user releases the mouse button and this will help you tell the click apart from the drag.

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem

> move the cursor to the empty space and then click the mouse button, the object is moved here.

I would suggest you remove your first `if` condition i.e.

```
if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
    if(gm)
    {
        gm.GetComponent<GameObject>();
        gm.transform.position=new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x,Input.mousePosition.y,1);
    }
}
```

This piece of code will move your character to your cursor position when ever you will click the left mouse button.

For your second problem:

> I also have to move camera towards object for zoom view

I see that you are changing the scale of your character, but I will suggest you change the position of your camera. All you will have to do is figure out how much close you want to move your camera and save that value (most probably you will only have to move the z-axis of your camera).